# Is there a restAPI that takes a flight number and returns airports?

Tags: flight-status

I am looking for a restAPI that takes a flight number (like 'KL705') and returns the departure and arrival airports.

Whenever you enter a flightnumber in google it will give a similar return.

Been looking all over but most API's ask to include date or airports.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s not about travelling

Comment: Not to mention, date or airports are required for such a search anyway.

Comment: @M.Jeffryes It is for an app to calculate your travel carbon-footprint and handles travel information. I have also seen other travel-data related questions here.

Comment: @michael Clearly with Google this is not the case

Comment: A flight number can actually be reused for several legs. For instance WN1520 is SFO-LAS then LAS-DEN. Also, the same flight number may have different itineraries depending on the date (e.g. not all the legs are flown each day, or a flight has an intermediate stop on certain days but not others...). Beyond the next few days, a flight number may be reused for a completely different flight...

Comment: You can always do the same thing Google does, and use the current date (and if no result is available, look up the next day, and so on until you reach a pre-set limit). But depending on what you want the data for, this may give unexpected results.

Comment: One extreme example: WN1069: today it's LAX-LAS-ABQ. On September 2nd (barely over a week ago!), it was DEN-MDW. Another example: UA1610 is EWR-MSY today. On October 12th it will be SFO-LAS.

Comment: Thanks @jcaron! I found a way to get all flight data through the Aviation Edge API. But after reading your insights I should prob check multiple dates to make sure it has no changing destination/arrival locations. Thanks again.